# How to show value of sqldatasource and value from code to dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown within gridview i have binded that dropdown with  datasource values.

i will select any value from dropdown then it will save in database.

now i want to show the database value in the top value in same dropdown with sqldatasource.

Suppose i have value in dropdown from sqldatasource is test,test1,test2.

Suppose i have selected test1 then it will save in database now i want that dropdown show this values test1,test,test1,test2

Please help me in this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing your insert code within the DataBound event. Something like this:

```
protected void myDropDownList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DropDownList dropDownList1 = (DropDownList)sender;
dropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(newItem.GetText(), newItem.GetValue()));
}
```

In the code above, newItem is just a static method that uses the database to get the latest item inserted. You can obviously use your own method/variables for that bit, but basically the ListItem method will create a new item for your drop down list.

Comment: Thanks for this code but it didnt work in my problem.

I want to show both values of dqldatasource and value from code behind together.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far as my code should show both (although it's untested).